# Stop input from sending empty values

Tags: php

I got a table that fills its rows using  requests data from a database.

The first cell is a `checkbox` that has the ID of the requests as the value and its name as an array and the last is an input text field that has its name as an array too.

What the program does is that it sends the checked values to a processing php file that changes the state of the checked requests and updates it's amount with the amount I send from the input text field.

It works perfectly only if I check the requests continuously, if I don't do it the text sends an empty position in the array and I update it as an empty amount.

I know this is because the check only sends it's value if it's checked and the text sends it anyway.

My question is how do I make the text field only send it's value if the check from that row is checked, I can't seem to find the answer by myself or in google, so please can someone point me to a solution to this problem?

Comment: The processing file just implodes the array values that I send and makes the update for every checked value.

Comment: You can always validate your information server side and skip values that come up empty.  There isn't really anything that is going to stop a text input from submitting depending on the state of a checkbox.

Comment: You are right, I was looking for a way to stop it from sending when I could do that.
Have to remember to think of multiple solutions to a problem, thanks, man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use the ID as the array index in all the text fields:

```
echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='$id'></td>
          ...
          <td><input type='text' name='value[$id]'></td></tr>";
```

Then when you're processing the inputs, you can do:

```
foreach($_POST['check'] as $id) {
    $value = $_POST['value'][$id];
    ...
}
```

It will still send all the other text fields, but this input processing loop will ignore them, because only checked boxes will be in `$_POST['check']`.